# How to play MOV,M4V, M4A files using flex or flash?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3

Is it possible to play these files in Adobe Flex or flash?

Answer (score 3):

Current version of Flash can play MOV, M4V and M4A provided they are only of type container "MP4", all quicktime files have litle variation of MP4, but if they contain pure video of type H.264 and audio of AAC only, then flash can play it.

Checkout [Flash Video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video), you will need converter to convert them to correct MP4 format, since MOV etc formats can have video as H.264 and audio as MP3, flash will not play it, flash only needs video as H.264 and audio as AAC only.

Comment: so we need to convert flv or mp4. Suppose we are giving direct file(sample.mov). flex could not play

Comment: mov is container, like a zip file, but contents inside container has to be in proper format, mov is same as mp4. But the internal track format should be H264 and AAC only.

Answer (score -3):

No, that's not possible.

The Flash-player only supports the FLV-format, so you will have to convert your files to FLV.

---

BTW, I'm assuming you want to load the files at runtime. You can import a MOV-file in your Flash IDE, which converts it to keyframes.

Comment: how can i import mov files in to my flex IDE

Comment: you can't, it is only supported in the Flash IDE.